# Is there a word that means the results of a test can only be positive or inconclusive?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there a word for this? For instance, a medical test where a positive result would be conclusive but any other result would not be.

Comment: I know only of the terms 'false positive' and 'false negative'.

Comment: *unfalsifiable*?

Comment: I'd have thought the medical profession wouldn't be too keen on such tests in the first place. Most tests are actually considered *indicative*, where a positive result needs further confirmation, but a negative result usually means the doctor can ignore that possibility and look for other causes. A test that can't actually eliminate the possibility of whatever you were testing for seems to me to be of limited value.

Comment: I regard *unfalsifiable* as not the proper word here because
*[falsifiability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability)* is an unrelated concept.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: such a test, in medicine or any other science, would not be as desirable a test as one that gave a definitive positive or a definitive negative. But then it would also be better than no test at all, and sometimes you don't have a choice of test.

Comment: @jwpat7: on thought, such a test _is_ related to the concept of falsifiability. A property of a test like the one under discussion, means that a theory can't be falsified -by that test- (but not that the theory is unfalsifiable altogether).

Comment: @Mitch: Obviously a test that gives a definitive answer one way or the other would always be much preferred. My point is that in medical diagnosis a test which at best can only confirm the *presence* of a disease is inherently less desirable than one which can eliminate that possibility. How highly would you value being tested for aids if there was no possibility of being told you're in the clear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use *[go/no-go test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go/no_go)*, which refers to a test that either certifies an item is satisfactory or does not so certify.  In that regard, a go/no-go test is much like the vast majority of tests used in [statistical hypothesis testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothesis_testing) or in confirmatory data analysis, *i.e.* tests which "either fail to reject the null hypothesis or reject it in favor of the alternative." I suggest reviewing the vocabulary in [hypothesis testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothesis_testing#Definition_of_terms) and [statistical inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_inference) references.

A neologism to consider: "witness test", as inspired by *[Miller-Rabin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) testing*, which either provides a witness (a certificate) that a number is composite, or fails to do so.

Answer (score 2):

A test "where a positive result would be conclusive but any other result would not be" (i.e. a test with very few false positives) has *high specificity*. A test with a small number of false negatives has *high sensitivity*.

The [Wikipedia page on sensitivity and specificity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity) currently provides a good overview. It also refers to the word [pathognomonic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathognomonic), which is a characteristic of one, and only one, disease.